# How to add a custom 3d object in awe.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d

I am trying to add a custom 3d object in awe.js, I have tried with the cubes and sphere geometries, but haven't found any documentation that facilitates adding a 3d object. Any ideas?

```js
  awe.projections.add({ 
            id:'n', 
            geometry:{ path:'cube.obj'}, 
      rotation:{ x:30, y:30, z:0 },
            material:{ 
            type: 'phong',
            color:0x000000, 
            },
          }, { poi_id: 'north' });
```

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 2):

using new libraries you can do it as shown below, I've copied that from my answer in another question ([awe.js Augmented Reality adding text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021703/awe-js-augmeted-reality-adding-text)).

```
awe.pois.add({ id:'jsartoolkit_marker_64', position: { x:0, y:0, z:0 }, scale: { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 } });
                awe.projections.add({ 
                              id:'marker_projection', 
                                    geometry: { path: 'models/obj/example.obj' }, // path to your model
                                    position: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
                                    rotation: { x: 0, y: 180, z: 0 },
                                    material:{ path: 'models/obj/example.mtl' }, // path to material if you're using one
                                    visible: false,
}, { poi_id: 'jsartoolkit_marker_64' }); // common point of interest, in this case the marker
```