# awe.js Augmented Reality adding text

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, awe

I'm trying to add text to awe.js project, using this tutorial I have came up with an attempt, https://www.sitepoint.com/augmented-reality-in-the-browser-with-awe-js/.

```
awe.projections.add({
    id: 'text',
    geometry: {shape: 'text', text: 'Hello World', font: 'times new roman', weight: 'normal', style: 'normal'},
    rotation: {y: 45},
    position: {x: -5, y: -31, z: -5},
    material: {
        type: 'phong',
        color: 0xFF0000
    }
}, {poi_id: 'marker'});
```

Then I have done some more research on the subject and tried in different way yet still not succeeded.

```
awe.pois.add({ id:'fixed_poi', position: { x:70, y:0, z:-250 }, visible: true });
                    awe.projections.add({ 
                      id:'fixed_projection', 
                                geometry: { shape: 'text', text: "My Text", parameters:{font: 'optimer', size: 50}},
                position: { x:0, y:0, z:0 },
                rotation: { x:0, y:0, z:0 },
                      material:{ type: 'phong', color: 0xFFFFFF },
                    }, { poi_id: 'fixed_poi' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create text model separately (an .obj 3D model) for example in 3D builder in Windows 10, and then add that to awe.js in following way:

```
awe.pois.add({ id:'jsartoolkit_marker_64', position: { x:0, y:0, z:0 }, scale: { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 } });
                awe.projections.add({ 
                              id:'marker_projection', 
                                    geometry: { path: 'models/obj/example.obj' }, // path to your model
                                    position: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
                                    rotation: { x: 0, y: 180, z: 0 },
                                    material:{ path: 'models/obj/example.mtl' }, // path to material if you're using one
                                    visible: false,
}, { poi_id: 'jsartoolkit_marker_64' }); // common point of interest, in this case the marker
```

Hope this helps